# why vim apply syntax(colors) to existing files only?

Tags: vim

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm trying to learn and use vim, but when I open a file, all the text has the same color, even when I use the hash for comments. That makes it hard to read, so I tried `:syntax on` but it only works on existing files, when I create a new one or modify the ones created by me, show the same color at all.
What can I do?

Comment: Hello! Non-programming questions related to VIM should be directed to [vi.se] SE.

Comment: Could you add the exact sequence of commands you are performing? Filetype detection, a prerequisite of syntax highlighting, is mostly based on extensions so doing `$ vim` and writing some C or whatever right away won't get you syntax highlighting. For that, you will need to either a) write the file with `:w foo.c`, which will trigger filetype detection, b) use `:file foo.c` to assign a filename to the current buffer without writing to disk, which will also trigger filetype detection, or  c) do `set filetype=c` or `:set syntax=c` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i am sorry for my lack of information provided, actually i found out it only doesn't work for the .txt files. I've tried to open some scripts i made before and it is taking the syntax highlighting, so how can i make it work for my documentations files i save as .txt files?

Comment: `*.txt` files have no specific syntax so there is no syntax highlighting to do. If you use a known syntax in your `*.txt` files and you want Vim to automatically assign it to `*.txt` files use SO's search: I'm sure such a question it has been answered before.